# Using CSS Clip with percentage

Tags: css, clip

I'm trying to display only the top half of an image and the bottom half of the same image in 2 separate divs.

I've tried with the CSS property `clip`, but it doesn't seem to support % as a unit.

Is it just me? Do you have a solution for displaying only a half of an image?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Update (after 5+ years):**

The CSS clip property is now deprecated. Consider using clip-path instead (allowing for a non-JS solution), which allows you to specify shapes with percentages. Example:

`/* Bottom half of image */
clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);`

`/* Top half of image */
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 50%);`

Further example to create a triangle using percentages:

`clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);`

**Original:**
CSS clip property does not currently support percentages:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-clip , latest http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visufx.html#clipping

A solution to your problem could be to use Javascript to determine the size of the area you want to show, and then use that value when setting the *clip* property. Something as simple as this should do the trick:

`var heightOfImageToDisplay = image.height / 2;`

Comment: This is what I'm doing for the moment, but a was looking for a solution without JS

Comment: Not a problem. Perhaps you should say that in your question so others can clearly see you don't want a JS solution :)

Comment: I totally accept JS solution if there is really no other solution :)

Comment: Clip-path's great! What clip should have been from the start. It even supports internal `calc()` operations.

Comment: Why must all the simple things in life like clip be depredicated, * sigh *

Answer (score 5):

Sorry that I don't have enough reputation to write a comment.

There's absolutely a solution **without JS**.

All you need to do is

1. Create an svg `clipPath`, which allows you define whatever path you want.
2. Set clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" for responsive clip path, which allows the usage of **percentage** path definition
3. Apply the `clipPath` in your css code.

   ```
   #your-element {
      clip-path: url(#clipPathId);
   }
   ```

If you want more information, please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28312070/5692151

Answer (score 0):

You could have the div as `position: relative;` and `overflow: hidden;`
Have the image inside as `position: absolute;`

And control how the image is displayed but setting a *height* to the div and adjust the *top* and *bottom* properties of the image

Comment: The problem is that the div which contain the image is already on absolute

Comment: What about a negative _margin-top_ value?

Comment: Already tried a `margin-top: 50%` but the problem is that it doesn't take the direct parent as reference for the %, so it comes with weird results

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fixed height images and fixed height `div`, and you are doing this manually, why not put the image as a background, with `overflow:hidden` and proper `background-position` so it only shows the top one from the top down and bottom one from the bottom up?