# How to clip an image on % of width and % of height

Tags: html, css

I tried few links but dint get anything fruitful.
I am working on this

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp

but in my case I need to clip the image on "%" rather than putting some predefined px values.
However I can not do this .

How to achieve that ??

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242222/using-css-clip-with-percentage

Answer (score 0):

The [Clip property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-clip) doesn't support percentages (yet). To achieve that effect, you can either:

1) Wrap the image in a div, set percentage width and height and overflow: hidden; For example:

```
<div id="test">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
</div>

div#test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmTA4/)

2) Instead of the image, use a div with percentage width and height and the image set as a background-image.

3) Use javascript to calculate the required width and height after the image has been rendered and work with that.

Comment: with this i will get a squeezed image ,what I want is like from the origin 10% of width and 10 % of height.

Comment: Which one of the 3 methods I recommended did you try? Did you try the other two? I have included an example that does what you wanted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in percentages, you can achieve it with an additional extra wrapper div with dimensions same as image.

Try following CSS and HTML.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="imgContainer">
      <!-- NOTE: image dimensions are same as in "wrapper" class-->
      <img src="path/to/img.jpg" width="200" height="140" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    width : 200px;
    height : 140px;
}
/* Below width and height are in percentage w.r.t. those in 
   'wrapper' class whose width and height are same as image.
*/
.imgContainer{
    width : 50%;
    height : 50%;
    overflow : hidden;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/RC3D5/).