# Is it possible to make a SVG clipPath with a <path> responsive?

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I am trying to make a responsive SVG with a bitmap pattern and a sort of complex shape with clipPath.

If I use a `<polygon>` instead of a `<path>` to create simpler shapes they are responsive, but I haven't achieved the same using a path, any ideas on how to achieve this or even if is possible?

Here's the code I have [and a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/edrpls/53tbbfk9/9/).

```
<!-- Path Test-->
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="assetContainer">
    <div class="asset">
      <svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="pathTest">
            <path d="M 0.1562378,0.5 H 323.76366 c 0,0 -20.4244,6.3661 -21.48541,47.4801 -1.06101,41.1141 19.8939,42.7056 21.22016,43.2361 1.32626,0.5305 -323.3421722,0 -323.3421722,0 0,0 19.6286472,-1.8568 19.8938992,-42.9708 C 20.315389,7.1313 0.1562378,0.5 0.1562378,0.5 Z"
            />
          </clipPath>

          <pattern x="0" y="0" width="84" height="70" id="img7" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/T66UMJs.png" width="84" height="70" x="0" y="0" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#img7)" clip-path="url(#pathTest)" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


/* CSS */

svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.assetContainer {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.asset {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: auto;
  left: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.mainContainer {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  //overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `<clipPath>` to use `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`.  When using objectBoundingBox units, your clip path coords map to the bounding box of the element they are being applied to.  (0,0) maps to the top left of the element. (1,1) maps to the bottom right.

You'll need to redefine your path (or apply a transform to convert the coords to this range). But once you do, it will automatically scale to fit whatever you apply it to.

Comment: Thanks @PaulLeBeau. Is there an easy way to convert the path? I tried dividing all the values by either the width or height set in the viewPort (0,0,300, 100), but the shape doesn't look at all how it's supposed to.

Comment: That would work as long as long as the viewport (viewBox?) you are using corresponds to the relative size of the object you are applying the clippath to. Alternatively, write a little bit of JavaScript to call the `getBBox()` function on the clippath's path. That will give you good the exact size of the path and hence the clippath will exactly fit the object.

Comment: I'm suffering with the same thing... can't understand how to achieve this easily... nobody says anything about it on the web...

Comment: Conversion solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210466/convert-svg-path-data-to-0-1-range) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495919/how-to-apply-clippath-to-a-div-with-the-clippath-position-being-relative-to-the) awesomely by @Lazar Vuckovic with the help of Robert Longson. Take a look there! <3