# Hexagonal Images

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

## Circle Images

I can get circle borders using `border-radius`:

```
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

## Hexagonal Images

I'm hoping to create **hexagonal** images though. I'm guessing that wrapping the images in a `div`/`span` (or a few of them) will be required.

Something like either of these:

[image]
[image]

For simplicity's sake, **all images are square**.

## Objective

The point of getting images like this is to stack them in a honeycomb like structure. I'm not putting this as part of the question as it should be relatively easy to achieve if I can get my images hexagonal.

Comment: To be fair, this question has been marked as a duplicate but has a far superior answer.

Comment: Then @matthewelsom should consider adding it as an answer to it.

Comment: @j08691 agreed, my point was not to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `clip-path`...

```css
img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200">
```

Here is a [jazzy tool](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) for easily generating the clip-path attribute.
And here is a [nice article](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) with more information.

Comment: @matthewelsom You might want to add your answer above the the duplicate answer linked at the top.

Comment: @jcuenod be aware that this solution will only work in webkit browsers. IE doesn't support the clip-path property and FF doesn't support polygon. More info on [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

Comment: However you could use inline svg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311741/responsive-clip-path-with-inline-svg

Comment: @jcuenod I provided an SVG approach in the duplicate question here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31284251/1811992