# HTML Image Hitbox

Tags: html, css, image, svg

[The hitbox of the SVG img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K33GO.png)I cant figure out how to get my Image to be the Hitbox of the image since it has curves and corners its not square.

I have tried it like this with svg tags aswell and it always ends up with the square hitbox I dont know how to continue. The Hitboxes should be the size of the IMG so that when i hover over it, it lights up

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
    <title>asdasd</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <img src="../Icons/menu.png" class="menu">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
        </div>
        <img src="Imgs/logo.jpeg" class="logo">
    </div>
    </div>
<main>
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="Imgs/9wdpMq01.svg">
    </object>
    <img src="Imgs/Ebene-3-Kopie.svg" alt="Test">
   
</main>
</body>
```

Comment: You would have to use a native SVG in the HTML and wrap the relevant components (Paths) in a link group

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<map>` and `<area>`.

```
<map name="customMap">
    <!-- Define the polygonal area coordinates for the hitbox -->
    <area shape="poly" coords="x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,..." href="#" alt="Description">
</map>
```

Replace the `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, ...` coordinates in the  element with your SVG coordinates. Make sure to add `shape="poly"` to the area tag!

Comment: I tried it, it didnt work any other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use an inline svg you can create a responsive `clip-path` and apply it to your `<img>` element.

I concatenated all paths to a single compound path and used [yoksel's clip-path generator](https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/) to get a scaled clip-path.

```css
body{
  background-color:#ccc;
  padding:1em;
}

img{
  width:70%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
}

img:hover {
  opacity:0.5;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<img id="exampleImg" src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M 51 0.01 A 50 50 0 0 1 84.641 13.945 L 63.418 35.169 A 20 20 0 0 0 51 30.025 z' fill='%23bacc33' class='segment segment-12_500 segment-1 '></path><path d='M 86.055 15.359 A 50 50 0 0 1 99.99 49 L 69.975 49 A 20 20 0 0 0 64.831 36.582 z' fill='%234fcc33' class='segment segment-12_500 segment-2 '></path><path d='M 99.99 51 A 50 50 0 1 1 49 0.01 L 49 30.025 A 20 20 0 1 0 69.975 51 z' fill='%23cc3333' class='segment segment-75_000 segment-3'></path></svg>">

<!-- hidden clip-path-->
<svg class="svg" style="position:absolute; width:0; height:0;">
  <clipPath id="my-clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"><path d="M0.51,0 A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,0.846,0.139 L0.634,0.352 A0.2,0.2,0,0,0,0.51,0.3 M0.861,0.154 A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,1,0.49 L0.7,0.49 A0.2,0.2,0,0,0,0.648,0.366 M1,0.51 A0.5,0.5,0,1,1,0.49,0 L0.49,0.3 A0.2,0.2,0,1,0,0.7,0.51" /></clipPath>
</svg>
```

#### Further reading:

- Smashing magazine: ["Managing SVG Interaction With The Pointer Events Property"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/svg-interaction-pointer-events-property/)
- SO: ["Responsive clip-path with inline SVG"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311741/responsive-clip-path-with-inline-svg#28312070)